# Laravel on AWS degrades when document root set to '/public'

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel application to Elastic Beanstalk, following [this tutorial provided.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html#php-laravel-tutorial-prereqs) It goes fine until I attempt to configure the site's document root, at which point the application degrades.

I checked the last 100 lines in the logs, which have the following under 'error logs' -

```
------------------------------------- 
/var/log/httpd/error_log
------------------------------------- 
[Wed Jun 07 15:15:58.282967 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 30331] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec) 
[Wed Jun 07 15:15:58.320391 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 30331] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ... 
[Wed Jun 07 15:15:58.320956 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 30331] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor 
[Wed Jun 07 15:15:58.397468 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30331] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Wed Jun 07 15:15:58.397492 2017] [core:notice] [pid 30331] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Any help is appreciated, let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Define "degrades", please? What exactly happens?

Comment: Ah... do you mean "degraded" in the [Beanstalk sense](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-status.html)?

Comment: Those error logs look normal output. I'd guess your EB instance is doing a health check to a file/route that no longer exists now that you've changed the root.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. After spending few hours, I could find the reason behind this issue. The problem was with the way we create a zip file for uploading the code to AWS.

Don't select the folder to archive it into a zip file. Instead, select all files within the folder and then add them to archive. If you select the complete folder for archiving, `/public` route can not be found and that creates a problem.

Read more [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html) before creating your zip file.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this. I had no idea what was causing the issue until I tried what you suggested and it worked.